# In a software RAID1, why does tune2fs -c 0 /dev/sda1 not throw an error but change is not seen in tune2fs -l /dev/sda1?

Tags: software-raid, mdadm, md, tune2fs, e2fsck

The Title pretty much says it all.

## Turn off mount count fsck seems to succeed:

`tune2fs -c 0 /dev/sda1`
`tune2fs -c 1 /dev/md0`

## But listing out via

`tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` shows mount count is set back to `1` for /dev/sda1 and /dev/md0.

i only want automatic file system checks on the **software** raid device, not the member drives, but it keeps going back on for the member drives.

Answer (score 0):

My member drives and the RAID1 drive all have the same UUID.  Will change the member UUIDs via:

### `tune2fs -U time /dev/sda1`

but now i have second thoughts because there seems to be conflicting views on whether the member drive UUIDs should equal the RAID UUID?

`# for fs in md1 sda2 sdb2; do tune2fs -l /dev/${fs} | egrep -i '(UUID|Hash Seed)'; done;

Filesystem UUID:          0de026e2-a1ce-461c-bb3f-c3982b064b4c
Directory Hash Seed:      0a5f8be8-965c-48b2-a0c6-3c1cd314a12f
Filesystem UUID:          0de026e2-a1ce-461c-bb3f-c3982b064b4c
Directory Hash Seed:      0a5f8be8-965c-48b2-a0c6-3c1cd314a12f
Filesystem UUID:          0de026e2-a1ce-461c-bb3f-c3982b064b4c
Directory Hash Seed:      0a5f8be8-965c-48b2-a0c6-3c1cd314a12f`

Comment: i don't thing is good idea work with raid member diveces "tune2fs -l /dev/sda1 
tune2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
"

Comment: @c4f4t0r, maybe you need to sudo up to root to get permissions to read the superblock.  `tune2fs -l /dev/sda1` provides the exact same output as `tune2fs -l /dev/md0` and that is why i have the problem - same UUIDs.

Comment: i'm using the root user.

Comment: @c4f4t0r, i am no expert, but i bet there is a problem with your drive.  Does `cat /proc/mdstat` say its UP and ok?  Maybe `echo check > /sys/block/md0/md/sync_action`  Consider repair as well.

Comment: @c4f4t0r, could you have the RAID member drive be the whole drive such as /dev/sda instead of a partition?  Try `tune2fs -l /dev/sda`

Comment: tune2fs -l /dev/sda
tune2fs 1.42.5 (29-Jul-2012)
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21871/discussion-between-c4f4t0r-and-rjt).

Answer (score 0):

Automatic file system checks at boot time are based on the information you have in the fstab.

This means either you have a problem in the /etc/fstab configuration or if you are using LABEL or UUID you have a problem how those block devices are configured. I suspect it it a problem related to udev, or udev configuration.

Comment: The member drives are definitely not in /etc/fstab.  Should the member drives in a RAID1 have the same UUID as the /dev/md0?

Comment: No, the UUID should be different. Could you please add the output of `lsblk --output NAME,KNAME,MAJ:MIN,FSTYPE,UUID`

Answer (score 0):

`/dev/md0` is a device on top of `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdX1`, the member drives of a RAID 1 array. This means that all changes that you make to a filesystem on `/dev/md0` will be propagated to both member drives. This is the answer to your question in the title.

It also means that the filesystem UUID is exactly the same on both `/dev/sdX1` and `/dev/mdo`.

Once you have set up RAID 1 with member devices, you should not make any changes to the member drives directly (including tune2fs etc.), because that might disturb the RAID operation.

What is the original problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: One problem is that e2fsck will possibly be performed directly against a member drive and it can't be turned off unless I 
A.remove the drive from the array,   
B.set a different GUID, then   
C. disable auto fsck, 
D. set GUID back to original Raid1 UUID and then.   
E. rejoin to array.UUID

Comment: What exactly would perform the e2fsck directly against a member drive? There is something wrong in the OS if this happens.

Comment: my other Raid1 has different UUIDs for each member and different again for the md disk.