# How to run fsck on software raid's real hard disks?

Tags: software-raid, fsck

When and how should this be run? Is it better to boot from a DVD-ROM and run fsck on each real hard drive? Or can this be done automatically after X number of mounts?

Comment: Possble duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/674694/how-to-have-automatic-file-system-checks-for-linux-software-raid/674728

Answer (score 5):

The answer to when to run `fsck` on the underlying physical disks is very simple:

**Never**

If you are using RAID-1 the `fsck` command might not notice you are using it incorrectly and perform an actual check. If that check results in any writes to the disk, you will end up with a RAID where the disks are out of sync.

Having metadata out of sync between RAID replicas can potentially lead to data loss.

**The correct way to check your RAID**

Periodic checks of the file system metadata are to be performed on the logical layer above the RAID. This is done as part of the boot process, and there is a good chance this is already configured for you.

Periodic verification that the replicas are readable and in sync is also a good idea. This happens at a lower layer and doesn't check any integrity at the file system layers. On one of my servers I can see that these checks are happening by inspecting the output of

```
dmesg | grep data-check
```

Comment: Red Hat-based systems have a cron job that rescans software RAID arrays every Sunday morning.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Debian has a cron job which does it the first Sunday of the month.

Answer (score 4):

fsck stands for 'file system consistency check', it checks a filesystem, not the underlying disks - as such it should be used to testing the entire filesystem. As for periodic automatic fsck executions look at your /etc/fstab file, it's in that file that we can define automatic checks.